# Android ListPreference - Preform a method on listItem select?

Tags: android, listpreference

I've created a ListPreference in PreferenceActivity and it works good:

- user clicks on the Preference item
- a list dialog opens (retrieves listItems and their values from array.xml)
- if the user selects one of the list items it saves his selection (which I can later retrieve).

My question is: how can I preform a method the second he presses one of the list items (according to the user selection)?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a `OnPreferenceChangeListener` for any given preference by calling its `setOnPreferenceChangeListener()` method.

Comment: Tried what you said:
Preference sorted = (Preference) findPreference("sortPref");
  sorted.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
   public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
    testing();    
    return true;
   }
  });

and it allows me to know if the Preference Item is clicked and not the listItem in the newly opened dialog...

Any ideas?

Comment: sortPref is the ListPreference key.
The dialog it opens is generated from arrays.xml which contains titles and values.

Comment: setOnPreferenceClickListener() should trigger when the user clicks the preference.  setOnPreferenceChangeListener() should trigger when they select a preference from the dialog.